# In Rspec, how do I set the VCR record mode in the feature description?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, vcr

I have a test that uses VCR like this:

`describe 'Do something with an api', feature: true, js: true, vcr: true do`
`end`

I want to set this vcr recording to the option `new_episodes` (it's currently set to `once`) but I can't find out how to pass this option into the settings. How to I make this feature record with the setting `new_episodes`?

https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-3/docs/record-modes/new-episodes - here's the docs for this option.

I can do it when wrapping a block in a vcr recording, however I want to use this setting for one of my features, how do I go about doing that? Can I pass it in on the `describe` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.9.3 is extremely old (current version appears to be 6.1.0).

That being said according to the docs, which show almost  this exact example, you can pass that option through the `:vcr` key in the `Hash`

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
VCR.configure do |c| 
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
end
```

And then

**spec/your_spec.rb**

```
describe 'Do something with an api', feature: true, js: true, vcr: {record: :new_episodes} do
```

- [2.9.3 Docs](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-3/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-rspec-metadata#pass-a-hash-to-set-the-cassette-options)
- [6.1.0 Docs](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-1-0/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-rspec-metadata#pass-a-hash-to-set-the-cassette-options)